# Replicating a java -jar execution through rJava

Tags: r, rjava

I have a java file that I would normally execute by doing

```r
java -jar jarname.jar arguments
```

I want to be able to run this file from R in the most system agnostic way possible. My current pipeline partially relies on rJava do identify JAVA_HOME and run the jar by doing

```r
# path for the example file below
pathToJar = 'pdftk-java.jar'
# start up java session
rJava::.jinit()
# find JAVA_HOME
javaPath = rJava::.jcall( 'java/lang/System', 'S', 'getProperty', 'java.home' )
# get all java files
javaFiles = list.files(javaPath,recursive = TRUE,full.names = TRUE)
# find java command
java = javaFiles[grepl('/java($|\\.exe)',javaFiles)]
# run the jar using system
system(glue::glue('{shQuote(java)} -jar {shQuote(pathToJar)} arguments'))
```

This does work fine but I was wondering if there was a reliable way to replicate execution of a jar through rJava itself. I want to do this because

- I want to avoid any possible system dependent issues when finding the java command from JAVA_HOME
- I already started an rJava session just to get the JAVA_HOME. I might as well use it since `.jinit` [isn't undoable](https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/25)
- I not that familiar with what calling a jar through -jar does and I am curious. Can it be done in a jar independent way? If not what should I look for in the code to know how to do this.

[This](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk/-/jobs/243952416/artifacts/raw/build/libs/pdftk-all.jar) is the file in I am working with. Taken from https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk/tree/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `JAR` file is (essentially) running class file that is embedded inside `JAR`.

Instead of calling system and executing it as external application, you can do following:

- make sure to add your `JAR` file to `CLASSPATH`

```r
rJava::.jaddClassPath(pathToJar)
```

- check inside `JAR` file what is the main class. Look into `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file to identify the main class. (In this case `com.gitlab.pdftk_java.pdftk`)
- instantiate class inside R.

```r
newObj = rJava::.jnew('com/gitlab/pdftk_java/pdftk')
```

- run the class following way: http://www.owsiak.org/running-java-code-in-r/

**Update**

Running `JAR` file (calling `main` method of Main-class) is the same things as calling any other method inside Java based class. Please note that `main` method takes array of Strings as argument. Take a look here for sample: http://www.owsiak.org/running-jar-file-from-r-using-rjava-without-spawning-new-process/

```r
newObj$main(rJava::.jarray('--version'))
```

For this specific case if you look at the source code for this class, you'll see that it terminates the session

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.exit(main_noexit(args));
  }
```

This will also terminate your R session. Since all `main` function does it to call `main_noexit` then exit, you can replace `main` with `main_noexit` in the code above.

```
newObj$main_noexit(rJava::.jarray('--version'))
```

Comment: This is fairly vague. I figured out that I need to look at the MANIFEST at the META_INF to find out what the main class is. Which in this case is `com.gitlab.pdftk_java.pdftk`. Using `.jaddClassPath(pathToJar)`, I added the jar to the classpath, and instantianted the class using .jnew. I am still unsure what to do after this. Presumably I need to do `.jcall(newObject,method='main')` yet when I try to do that it fails to find the method with the right signature. However, looking at the the source code, the main method for the class is defined as `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: I see that I can also see methods available to the class using the `$` operator. But using `newObject$main('--version')` for instance gives a error, telling me that `No suitable method for the given parameters`. But as far as I understand this should be a fine input since it is asking for a string

Comment: The reason here is that `main` expects array of strings - not a string.

Comment: I see so I need to use the output of `.jarray` as an input to the `main` function. In this particular case, `main` function includes a `System.exit` which apparently is authoritative enough to shut down the R session. So I need to use the `main_noexit` which is helpfully included as well. I guess in some cases, this will force me to modify the java code to manually remove the `System.exit` command

Comment: If the code has `System.exit` it’s a bad luck. You can still use security manager to prevent execution of `System.exit’`